# Why PHP Zend_Date get method is outputting wrong value for some dates in 2016 and 2017?

Tags: php, datetime, zend-framework

When using PHP Zend_Date get method I am seeing incorrect output for some dates in year 2016 and 2017 only. For year 2014, 2015 and 2018, 2019 expected output date is correct but for year 2016 and 2017 output date is one year back.

```
public function date{

    $return_format = 'Y-M-d HH:m:s';
    $locale = null;


    $date1 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2014 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date1->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2014-1-1 00:00:00
    // CORRECT

    $date2 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date2->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2015-1-1 00:00:00
    // CORRECT

    $date3 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date2->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2015-1-1 00:00:00
    // INCORRECT - Year is one year behind 

    $date4 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date2->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2016-1-1 00:00:00
    // INCORRECT - Year is one year behind

    $date5 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2018 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date2->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2018-1-1 00:00:00
    // CORRECT

    $date6 = new Zend_Date(strtotime ("Jan 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM"));
    error_log($date2->get($return_format, $locale));
    // outputs 2019-1-1 00:00:00
    // CORRECT

}
```

Also Note: For both 2016 and 2017 the output is 2015 and 2016 respectively for January 1, 2 and 3. January 4th onwards is expected output.